# Pandas DataFrame column assignment ValueError: Wrong number of items passed

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, quantitative-finance

I am having an issue with a script that was functioning prior to an upgrade of Anaconda (thus an upgrade of pandas and numpy)

I have a DataFrame that I would like to use one column from and multiply by the values in a column of another DataFrame, outputting the final value to a column in a new DataFrame. As I said this code was working until I upgraded to pandas 0.17.

```
class MarketOnClosePortfolio(Portfolio):
    def __init__(self, symbol, bars, signals, initial_capital=10000.0):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.bars = bars
        self.signals = signals
        self.initial_capital = float(initial_capital)
        self.positions = self.generate_positions()

    def generate_positions(self):
        positions = pd.DataFrame(index=signals.index).fillna(0.0)
        positions[self.symbol] = signals['signal']*10

        return positions        

    def backtest_portfolio(self):
        portfolio = self.positions*self.bars['Close']
        pos_diff = self.positions.diff()

        portfolio = pd.DataFrame(index=signals.index)
        portfolio['holdings'] = (self.positions*self.bars['Close'])
        portfolio['cash'] = self.initial_capital - (pos_diff*self.bars['Close']).sum(axis=1).cumsum()

        portfolio['total'] = portfolio['cash'] + portfolio['holdings']
        portfolio['returns'] = portfolio['total'].pct_change()

        return portfolio

if __name__ == "__main__":
    portfolio = MarketOnClosePortfolio(symbol, bars, signals, initial_capital=10000.0)
    returns = portfolio.backtest_portfolio()
```

My error comes in when trying to execute `returns = portfolio.backtest_portfolio()` referring back to `portfolio['holdings'] = self.positions*self.bars['Close']` and returns

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3509, placement implies 1.

self.positions has this appearance (its index is around 3600):

```
    Symbol
1    int
2    int
3    int
```

self.bars.Close has this apperance (same index size as self.positions):

```
    Close
1   float
2   float
3   float
```

Am i overlooking something obvious here? I know I am passing a series and not a single value, but i am confused why i am getting "placement implies 1" out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Stefan. self.positions is a dataframe in form of                                              `symbol                                                                                                                       index      value` its about 3600 lines long.

Comment: Have you tried self.positions.shape and self.bars['close'].shape? Looks like you are creating `portfolio` twice, by the way. I would guess that `self.bars['Close']` is only selecting a single item, possibly by `row index`, as opposed to a `column` as you may be intending. Might want to try `self.bars.loc[:, 'Close']]` instead.

Comment: ok. interesting. it self.bars.Close.shape returns (3559, ) but when i print(bars.head()) it has all of the expected values. self.positions.shape returns the same index value with 1 column as it should have. (3559, 1)

Comment: Are you trying to multiply `self.bars.close` with all `columns` in `self.positions`? It's a bit of guesswork without seeing the `data`..

Comment: Yes I am. self.positions only has one column (symbol) defining the positions in a given stock symbol. I added a small sample of the data format in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adjusting your multiplication along the lines of the below:

```
position = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': [ 1,2,3,4,5]})
bar = pd.DataFrame({'close': np.random.random(5)})

position.symbol.mul(bar.close, axis=0)

0    0.184591
1    1.830434
2    0.343875
3    1.531412
4    2.257981
dtype: float64
```

Comment: running `portfolio['holdings'] = position.symbol.mul(bar.close)` outputs a dataframe with the index passed through as columns with symbol on the end. ie of shape (3559, 3560)

Comment: Try adding the `axis=0` keyword to ensure alignment on index - assuming these are compatible?

Comment: Thanks! Looks like we're getting somewhere now. Changing axis=0 solved the multiplication issue, while also adding in a column with the title of the symbol in question. However my cash column is sitll not operating at all. just posting the original cash value as opposed to the value less the original cost of the purchased stock. I'll see what i can do about this.

Comment: On `cash`: looks like it's a `float` value from `__init__` but you are then trying to subtract a `Series` when using `.sum(axis=1).cumsum()`. Perhaps that line should be `sum(axis=1).sum()` so you also have a number there?

Comment: You are always helpful and online. Thanks! So i actually just removed .sum() entirely and instead used `portfolio['cash']=self.initial_capital-pos_diff.mul(self.bars.Close, axis=0).cumsum()`. This seems to have solved the problem.