# Change in pandas Dataframe column assignment behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I am curious about changes in Pandas between release 0.15.2 and 0.17 that affected the behavior of assigning Dataframe columns. The following formerly functioned properly:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

initial_capital = 10000
short_window = 30
long_window = 60
symbol = 'DIA'


bars = pd.read_csv(r'http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=10d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=DIA', skiprows=7, header=None, names=['Date', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume'])

signals = pd.DataFrame(index=bars.index)
signals['signal'] = 0.0 
signals['short_mavg'] = pd.ewma(bars['Close'], span=short_window, min_periods=1)
signals['long_mavg'] = pd.ewma(bars['Close'], span=long_window, min_periods=1)
signals['signal'][short_window:] = np.where(signals['short_mavg'][short_window:] > signals['long_mavg'][short_window:], 1.0, -1.0)
signals['positions'] = signals['signal'].diff() 

positions = pd.DataFrame(index=signals.index).fillna(0.0)
positions[symbol] = signals['signal']*10
portfolio = positions*bars.Close
pos_diff = positions.diff()
portfolio['holdings'] = positions*bars.Close
portfolio['cash'] = initial_capital - (pos_diff*bars.Close).cumsum()
portfolio['total'] = portfolio['cash'] + portfolio['holdings']
portfolio['returns'] = portfolio['total'].pct_change()
```

But as of updating to pandas 0.17 this raises an ValueError `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3391, placement implies 1` (the number of items passed may be different as the data feed updates minute by minute between 930A EST and 4P EST on weekdays)

Now, per the advice of [Stefan in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620118/pandas-dataframe-column-assignment-valueerror-wrong-number-of-items-passed), I have been able to rectify the code and get it working again. The functioning code is the same as above with changes beginning at line 21 as follows:

```
portfolio = positions.mul(bars.Close, axis=0)
pos_diff = positions.diff()
portfolio['holdings'] = positions.mul(bars.Close, axis=0)
portfolio['cash'] = initial_capital - (pos_diff.mul(bars.Close, axis=0)).cumsum()
```

From what i can gather from the release notes there has been a longterm problem with broadcasting arithmetic operations along datetime indexes [see here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2304) and that this was finally removed. The new behavior recommends replacing `df <op> df.A` with `df.<op>(df.A, axis=0 or 'index')`. This seems akin to my problem, however the index of my `bars` dataframe is not set to any of the columns, and the 'Date' column is read as an object dtype because of its formatting.

Can someone explain why it is that I need to use the new formatting of `df.<op>(df.A, axis=0)` to successfully carry out arithmetic operations across my dataframes despite not having a datetime index.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: For what it's worth, I get exactly the same error that you mention when trying the above code with pandas 0.15.2. Are you sure the error only appeared after upgrading pandas?

Comment: Yep. Literally ran it less than five minutes before upgrading and immediately afterwards. It was a full anaconda upgrade so I'm assuming numpy was upgraded as well, but still strange. It's not like its a big deal since the changes were just on a few lines, but i'd still like to know the reason behind it.

Comment: Well, I don't think the reason lies in pandas. The critical point is in: `positions*bars.Close` where you multiply a dataframe (of one column) with a series, and this aligment of the series on the columns of the dataframe has always been the case. So it is very unlikely that this worked correctly in 0.15.2

Comment: You can always quickly create a conda environment `conda create -n panda015 pandas=0.15.2` to check of you want.

Comment: @joris Thanks for the tip. Still kinda new to this so that is really useful. And the original code works again on my system when using the pandas 0.15.2 environment. Strange. If it matters at all the environment is also running numpy 1.10 and matplotlib 1.5